# Decode Chinese Address

Tags: translation

I'm trying to contact a person in China. He needs to pick his item from Customs, or it will be shipped back to me. I only have his address (he is not responding to my messages for some reason). Could you help me decript/translate it?

lei wang
02F#4Lvhaimingju17051267230
bao an Chandao road
shenzhen, GD 518101
China

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest that you put a fake address publicly.

Comment: I  agree with @PdotWang. Replace parts of the address and make it safer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?
广东省深圳市宝安区铲岛路 绿海名居02F#4  王磊  17051267230